# How to close browser window with a dialog popup using jQuery function?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project but need to know how to close the browser window and also show a dialog box if I would like to exit the page, using jQuery.

Thanks Rick, this helps, it brings up the  dafault chrome pop up dialog, I am trying to customize it to use my dialog in my javascrip file so it can prompt it when the user closes the page.. here is my code function ConfirmationDialog(baseURI) {
        var dialog = jQuery('Are you sure you want to exit this form without saving?').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'dialog'
    }).css("display", "none").appendTo('body');

```
jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Confirm',
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            window.location = baseURI;
            //                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To close browser:

```
window.close();
```

To prompt user:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var message = "Are you sure you want to leave?";

    (e || window.event).returnValue = message;
    return message;
});
```

Comment: Actually I tried it and it did not work... I added the script under my java script file for the project which is referenced to all my layout pages, but just closes window, no prompt shown, Am I adding this to the right page?

Comment: Thanks rick, look at updated question. maybe you can help me customize this query to use the referenced code above